# Algo to find least amount of items that satisfy a given requirement

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

I want to implement an **algorithm** for the following problem. It later on needs to be implemented in `T-SQL`:

- I have a set of **providers** - lets say shops. Each shop has it set of items it offers. Some items **overlap** between shops, some are only present in one shop.
- I have a list of items - lets say a `shopping` list with a set of items I want.

I now have to find the combination of shops which offer `ALL` the items while requiring the least amount of shops.

I am pretty sure this problem is frequently solved and the algorithm has its own name but I was not able to find it via search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I think I misinterpret the question the first time. Your problem is essentially a [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is NP-Complete. There are heuristic approaches however no optimal solution.

(This is similar but not quite your problem, worth looking at though) [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about any particular algorithm.  But given your requirements, I would:

- Start looking for the shop with the largest number of matching items from your list.
- Iterate until you fill your list.

If you want to really optimize this, you can then look for any redundant shops. A redundant shop would have items provided by one or more of the other shops in your list.

On a second thought, this could be solved using binary linear programming. Where each shop is variable, and the constraints are such that each item must be served by at least one shop.  You then try to minimize the number of shops.  Not sure how you would solve this inside T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - this is something I'll look into as a "real" solution of the set cover problem does not seem to be a trivial issue.